# Instagram API -Get the unfollowed and followed user data for a 1 million user following account?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have an `Instagram` account that has 1 million followers.
Now I need to track my followers. I need to know who unfollowed me and follwed me per day basis.
I have gone through the `Instagram API` and found that there is only 5000 requests permitted in an hour.
Is there any other way around to find who unfollowed me and followed me today?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Catalin I had to run a cronjob and save the data in a database. From there I am checking the followed status now.

Comment: so basically in day 1 you save using instagram api the entire list of followers, and in day 2 you save it again, and then compare list 1 with list 2 and see who unfollowed/followed you. Is it possible to save each day the entire list of 1 mil folllowers? Don't you have some limitations as you mentioned above?

Comment: @Catalin Nope. Not like that. Anyway we are permitted to send only 5000 requested per hour in Instagram. So I regularlly run a cron job to fetch the details from the instagram and save it in the database. So In one request I can get 20 values so in a hour I can get 20*5000 = 100000 values. So for that hour I will save this data. And In the next hour I will run the cron job for next section. All the comparison is made from the DB.

Comment: You are saying that you receive only 20 followers per request? That's strange because I get like 120....
Questions 2: the 5000 limitation is for 1 single account/token right? So I can do the same approach for the instagram accounts connected with my app?